# Beginning to Learn MVC for ToDoList

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Not too long ago, I was on here asking for help on a ToDoList I created in jQuery. I managed to complete that to the best of my ability, although, I moved onto MVC. I have watched a few tutorials and went over a few lessons in books, but I still don't understand it. What I do understand perfectly is the separation of concerns (learned that in college). I think that once I learn to use it will, I will love it. So, the problem I have is probably really simple.

I know how to make a view and a controller, and how to "link" them together. I also know about ViewBag (pretty clever I may add), but I don't know how to make a Model appear in a view. I have done lessons that did it, but maybe I am just missing something here.

Any help would be great!

Thanks.

By the way, here is my code:

```
ToDoListController:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Security;
using MvcMovie.Models;

namespace MvcMovie.Controllers
{
    public class ToDoListController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /ToDoList/

        public ActionResult Index(ToDoList model)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

    }
}

ToDoListModels:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
    public class ToDoList
    {
        public int ListID { get; set; }
        public String TaskName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you try send the data for json?
If you create a view with those fields, you can send the data via json.

for example

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("ToDoList","IndexResponse",new{Model.ListID}))
{
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaskName)
...
}

public ActionResult IndexResponse(ToDoList model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is quite simple. You are missing `[HttpPost]` attribute above your Action method.

> but I don't know how to make a Model appear in a view.

When you have some model for example:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public string TestStringProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And if you want to have bidirectional coommunication betweend view and controller you have to create a view in a html form- this is the way how you communicate with your server from a view.

```
@model NamespaceOfYourModel.TestViewModel

@using(Html.BeginForm("TestAction", "ToDoListController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TestId)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TestStringProperty)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.TestStringProperty)

    <input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="Save" />
}
```

Now you have to write two methods wchich will: first send new model object to the view secondly getting the model passed from view when form will be submited.

```
public ActionResult TestAction()
{
    //creating new object of your model
    TestViewModel testModel = new TestViewModel();

    //it will be 1 in the second method too
    testModel.TestId = 1;
    //passing model to the view
    return View(testModel);
}

//You say you want that method to be called when form is submited 
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestAction(TestViewModel testModel)
{
    if(testModel != null)
    {
        //you will see that the testModel will have value passed in a view
        var imNotNull = testModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to have `HttpPost` attribute on method if you want to use POST on it - if you does not specify the HTTP method, you can use any of them. `HttpPost` declares that this method could be used only via HTTP POST.